# How to unbind a RenderTarget texture so it can be used as input to the next pass

Tags: c++, direct3d, hlsl

I have a texture, along with its shaderresourceview, to which I render my scene's original image by using it as a RenderTarget.

Like millions before me, I then use it as an input to my next shader so I can blur, do HDR, all of that.

The simple but "new to me" problem is that when I go to call PSSetShaderResources and put the texture into the shader's texture/constant buffer I get this error:

```
"Resource being set to PS shader resource slot 0 is still bound on output"
```

...which makes sense, as it may still well be.  My question is how do I unbind the texture from being the render target of the initial pass?

I'm already doing this, which I presume sets it back to the original RenderTargetView that DXUT was using at the beginning, but it doesn't seem to free up the texture:

```
ID3D11RenderTargetView * renderTargetViewArrayTQ[1] = { DXUTGetD3D11RenderTargetView() };
pd3dImmediateContext->OMSetRenderTargets(1, renderTargetViewArray, nullptr);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming your render target is in slot 0:

ID3D11RenderTargetView* nullRTV = nullptr;
d3dContext->OMSetRenderTargets(1, &nullRTV, nullptr);

You need to pass an array of ID3D11RenderTargetView* of length 1, the first of which needs to be nullptr.

Comment: I revised the end of the question to reflect that I'm already setting a -different- render target (the original).  Would the intermediate step of setting it to null accomplish anything different?  Thanks!

Comment: Why is your array called "renderTargetViewArrayTQ" but the one you pass to OMSetRenderTargets called "renderTargetViewArray"?

Comment: Didn't fix the issue, but clearly a bug that's in the way of it ever working, so I'm marking as the answer to this one.  Thanks!

Comment: @AdamMiles What if your render target is not @ slot 0?

Answer (score 2):

When unbinding the texture from the pixel shader, this does NOT work:

```
    ID3D11ShaderResourceView *const pSRV[1] = { NULL };
    pd3dImmediateContext->PSSetShaderResources(0, 0, pSRV);
```

However, this DOES work:

```
    ID3D11ShaderResourceView *const pSRV[1] = { NULL };
    pd3dImmediateContext->PSSetShaderResources(0, 1, pSRV);
```

Put more simply, when setting the resource back to null, you still have to tell it you're passing in one pointer, albeit a null one.  Passing a null alone with a zero count appears to do nothing.